# Is "main focus" considered bad form?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Is using "main focus" considered bad form or redundant? I started thinking about this since the spelling function in MS Word highlighted it and suggested "main focus" -> "focus". I can see why it might be considered redundant, since both words indicate strong attention. However, to me, "main focus" can still be reasonable to use, since you e.g. can work/focus on a number of things, while still having one main focus.

Comment: MS Word is a tool, it's there to *suggest* that you might want to reconsider certain aspects. You are not obliged to listen to it, you are free to create whatever combination of words that so pleases you. The expression "main focus" is used daily, hourly, every single minute. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, it's not like I follow MS Word blindly - I just hadn't thought about it before and wondered if it might annoy some readers.

Comment: Google Books has over six million results for [**the main focus**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22the+main+focus%22) You might even argue it is *overused*.

Comment: The point to note is that *main* dilutes the force of *focus.* Rather than intensifying, it tends to suggest that it's one among several, a needless distraction in many contexts.

Comment: @Kris Excellent comment, and probably the main point to consider. I think you should post it as an answer. In my particular case, this is actually what I was going for, but hadn't thought of it as a diluting effect. Skipping "main" to me almost indicates sole focus, while I want to imply "main but not only focus".

Answer (score 2):

You could try "primary focus". It is commonly used as well, and means pretty much the same as "main", but suggests that you might have prioritized the other foci (secondary, tertiary, quaternary, quinary.....).

Answer (score -1):

Biologically speaking, you *can't* focus on two things at the same time.  Your eyes won't do it and neither will your brain (though then can switch focus very quickly). When people use 'main focus' what is often meant is 'main concern'. Substitute that if 'main focus' makes you uncomfortable.

If "concern" doesn't work, "main topic" or "main area of interest" are other possibilities.

Comment: Good point, but in my current text "main focus" is referring to topics that have received the most focus in the past, over time ("So far, the main focus has been..."). "Main concern" does not work well there.

Comment: I repeatedly stumbled upon the word *foci*, i.e. the plural of *focus*. So I guess this highly intellectual form (note the correct latin inflection) might justify the need to focus on a particular one out of multiple *foci*.

Comment: @fileunderwater: you might say "topics that have received the most attention" rather than "focus", if that helps you refocus your attention away from the word "focus". ;)

Comment: @dnagirl +1 for refocusing away from focus ;)

Answer (score -2):

"Main focus" sounds as though it came from soneone not familiar with the subtleties of English. "Principal" or "primary" would be better words. In fileunderwaters' response, "the most focus" really means in plain English "the most attention." Focus does not seem to be a matter of degree; you are either focussed or you are not.

Comment: It is certainly not impossible that "main focus" is more common among non-native speakers, but I kind of doubt it. As @Mari-LouA linked above, the expression is found six million times in Google Books, often in books by native speakers, and I've heard native speakers use the same expression.